# AngularJS testing with Jasmine unable to call "angular.mock.module" while using angular-mocks.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to get a basic unit test working and am running into an issue using angular-mocks.js. Hopefully this code will explain my situation.

```
describe("peconfigApp", function () {

    beforeEach(function() {
        angular.mock.module('peconfigApp');
    });

    describe("Binaries Controller", function () {
        it("should work", function () {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });

});
```

Jasmine result error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'module'
   at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:58141/Tests/js/controller-tests.js:4:22)
   at jasmine.Block.execute (http://localhost:58141/Tests/lib/jasmine.js:1064:17)
```

I've placed alerts in different parts of the code to verify that angular-mocks.js is loading before my tests load and run so I am pretty sure loading is not an issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller-tests.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I moved the angular-mocks load after the jasmine loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller-tests.js"></script>
```

This makes it work. Dumb problem, I must have missed this somewhere while reading through docs and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

In order to setup the `module` in your unit test you usually would do something like this:

```
beforeEach(module('peconfigApp'));
```

As long as your config is set up correctly (to pull in the correct files), that should allow you to then address the module in the test.

[The documentation on unit testing](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.unit-testing) is pretty good and worth a couple reads.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent an hour trying to get jasmine to read my controllers, etc. Everything has to be in the exact right order as Chris says.

**my index.html for running jasmine:**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>

    <link href="jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Init Angular -->
    <script src="../angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <!-- My code -->
    <script src="../app/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="../app/main.js"></script>
    <script src="../app/service.js"></script>

    <!-- Init Jasmine -->
    <script src="../jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="../jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular-mocks.js"></script>

    <!-- Insert spec's-->
    <script src="spec/controller.spec.js"></script>

    <!-- And GO! -->
    <script src="runner.js"></script>

    <!-- A basic test to check "connectivity" -->
    <div id="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <h1>Say something... {{data.variablehere}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="HTMLReporter" class="jasmine_reporter"></div>


</body>

</html>
```