# Unable to use $compile in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm working on an AngularJS app that uses a custom directive. I'm also trying to use unit testing in my app. So, I'm trying to leverage Jasmine for that. Currently, My unit test is the problem. Currently, it looks like the following:

**myDirective.spec.js**

```
describe('Directive: myDirective', function () {
  describe('Function: myProcedure', function () {
    it('should word', function ($rootScope, $compile) {     
      var e = angular.element('<div><br /></div>');
    console.log($compile);
      $compile(e)($rootScope);

      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

This test is throwing an exception. When the console.log line is ran, it prints: 'undefined'. The next line throws an error to Jasmine that says: 'TypeError: undefined is not a function'.

Its like I'm not injecting the $compile service. However, I believe I'm doing so. My test runner looks like the following:

```
<html ng-app="testApp">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/boot.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="directives/myDirective.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tests/unit/myDirective.spec.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <a href="#" onclick="env.execute()">run tests</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Why cannot I not run this basic test? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you must add angular mocks:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-mocks.js">
</script>
```

then load the modules and inject $compile/$rootScope in `beforeEach` blocks:

```
describe('Directive: myDirective', function () {
  var $compile;
  var $rootScope;

  beforeEach(module('testApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  describe('Function: myProcedure', function () {
    it('should word', function () {     
      var e = angular.element('<div><br /></div>');

      $compile(e)($rootScope);    
      expect(true).toBe(true);

    });
  });
});
```

Check unit testing docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.unit-testing#directives

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to get this approach working. When I attempt to run my tests, I get an error that says: ReferenceError: module is not defined. What am I missing?

Comment: Wow. I had tried for a while. Then I went to bed woke up. Wrote a different Google query and here's what I came to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109235/angularjs-testing-with-jasmine-unable-to-call-angular-mock-module-while-using

Comment: Updated unit testing docs link: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-directives

Answer (score 0):

The it() function provided by jasmine won't do any injection for you, so you need to inject your angular components into your tests. Modify your test as follows:

```
describe('Directive: myDirective', function () {
  describe('Function: myProcedure', function () {
    it('should word', function () {     
      inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        var e = angular.element('<div><br /></div>');
        //rest of code goes here
      });
```

You also need a reference to the [angular.mocks library](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock).

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem just now and this is what made my day (in the very end of it actually).just add "module('ng');" along with module('yourAppModule'). It should work.